# Is the union of a transitive relation and its inverse transitive?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I know that the inverse of transitive relations is transitive.

I also know that the union of two transitive relations is not always transitive.

However, what about the union between a transitive relation and its inverse. Is the resulting relation always transitive?

Comment: Consider the relation $R$ on $\{a,b,c\}$ defined by $R=\{(a,b),(c,b)\}$. This is transitive. The inverse is $R^{-1}=\{(b,a),(b,c)\}$. Their union is $S=R\cup R^{-1}=\{(a,b),(b,a),(b,c),(c,b)\}$ is not transitive, since $(a,b),(b,c)\in S$, but $(a,c)\not\in S$.

Comment: @plop Should probably make that an answer